# derivative of a trace and log determinant

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How can I find the derivative of the following two functions with respect to X.

$tr((A + XBX' + CX' + XD)^{-1}E)$

log$|(A + XBX' + CX' + XD)|$

where $A$, $B$ and $E$ are positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Define some new matrix variables for convenience
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= A + XBX^T + CX^T + XD \cr
dY &= dX\,BX^T + +XB\,dX^T + C\,dX^T + dX\,D \cr
W &= Y^{-1}EY^{-1} \cr
}$$
Find the differential and gradient of the first function 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm tr}(Y^{-1}E) = E^T:Y^{-1} \cr\cr
df &= E^T:dY^{-1} \cr
   &= -E^T:Y^{-1}\,dY\,Y^{-1} \cr
   &= -W^T:dY \cr
   &= -W^T:(dX\,BX^T + XB\,dX^T + C\,dX^T + dX\,D) \cr
   &= -(W^TXB^T + WXB + WC + W^TD^T):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}
   &= -(W^TXB^T + WXB + WC + W^TD^T) \cr
}$$
Do the same for the second function -- the algebra is very similar just replace $(-W)$ with $Y^{-1}$ in the final steps 
$$\eqalign{
 s &= \log\det Y \cr\cr
ds &= d\log\det Y \cr 
   &= d{\rm tr}(\log Y) \cr
   &= Y^{-T}:dY \cr
   &= Y^{-T}:(dX\,BX^T + XB\,dX^T + C\,dX^T + dX\,D) \cr
   &= (Y^{-T}XB^T + Y^{-1}XB + Y^{-1}C + Y^{-T}D^T):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial s}{\partial X}
   &= Y^{-T}XB^T + Y^{-1}XB + Y^{-1}C + Y^{-T}D^T \cr\cr
}$$
In these derivations, a colon was used to represent the inner/Frobenius product, which is merely an alternative notation for the trace, i.e. 
$$A:BC={\rm tr}(A^TBC)$$
The properties of the trace give rise to lots of rules for rearranging the Frobenius product, such as
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. I can roughly understand whats going on. I am bit new to this. Will you be able to recommend me a book or lecturer notes to refer.

Comment: I mean this notation.